# Custom redirect after "admin create user"

Tags: redirection, users

For usability of the system when a admin role creates a new user. The admin wants to edit user details but to do this he/she now needs to go to the user and click on "Edit" first.

Is there a way to redirect to this created user's "Edit" page immediately after creating that user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use form alter and redirect to any page you want

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state,$form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_register_form':
          $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_user_register_submit';
      break;
  }
}

function custom_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $uid = $form['#user']->uid;
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'user/'.$uid.'/edit';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) module. This may solve your query.

Or you can do this by using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Comment: Isn't that only for users who login? I want that the admin get's redirected after he (the admin) creates a new user and the admin can edit that user

Comment: If admin can register the user, then why admin need to goto again there edit profile page. He can fill full profile at the time of registration.